# Array to string conversion using PHP end()

Tags: php

I am trying to assign the last element of an array to a variable code extract as below:

```
92 //Get the list of numbers used from the database
93 $lastNumbersUsed = get_membership_numbers($typePrefix);
94 
95   foreach($lastNumbersUsed as $value){
96      echo $value["membershipNumber"] . "</br>";
97   }
98 //move to the last number
99 $lastNumber = end($lastNumbersUsed);
**100   echo("The last number is " . $lastNumber);
```

The Output for lines 92 to 97 is a follows: 2 string elements as expected
F100
F101

However attempting to assign the last element at line 99 produces:

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs....\index.php on line 100
The last number is Array

Any help gratefully received

Comment: use `var_dump()` if you're unsure what type a variable is. The assignment in line 99 is not the issue, it's trying to echo an array in line 100.

Comment: In your foreach loop over `$lastNumbersUsed`, where each element from that array becomes available in `$value`, you used `$value["membershipNumber"]` to access the actual number. And now, a couple of lines later, you suddenly forgot how to access the value you are looking for in a single item picked out of your array ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$lastNumbersUsed is two dimensional array and end function return last item that refer to array so the value of variable $lastNumber  is array , you must say
$lastNumber[index]
[review this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oNcG.png)